# Wordpress pages images directory

Tags: php, wordpress

So.. I'm creating a web pages using Wordpress.. I display contents by editing a page with the template of

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Pages
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria. Please try again.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But the Wordpress Pages Textarea filters my php code in this block

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pinterest.png" alt=""/>
```

So what I did is I replaced it with absolute URL like src="http://localhost/wordpress/theme. ... and so on

But I think there's a correct way to do it. Any suggestion/ideas?

Comment: Try this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/ or just take a look at how they've done it. You won't be able to use PHP directly, but their shortcode method should achieve the results you want.

Comment: If you are making the template , why do you need to put the PHP code in the text area inside the editor and not in the template ?

Comment: Coz I'll be only using one template in 5+ pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, create a shortcode that you can use by adding a snippet in functions.php.. This website gives a pretty good example

http://wpsnacks.com/wordpress-code-snippets/how-to-create-a-shortcode-to-display-the-wordpress-theme-path/